# How can i change my homepage layout to be 2 column and 1 column at the same time?

Tags: page-layouts

I currently have my homepage layout set to: 2 columns with left bar.. and i want to look just like in the picture.. 
I've run out of ideas and i'm asking for your help..
I'm currently running on a custom theme and my magento version is 1.9.0.1

I really need your help.. 
Thank you

[image: this is how i want it to be..]

Answer (score 2):

You can set it **1 column** layout and then in that layout, you can create two floated DIVs for left menu and right slider. Other elements like top menu and bottom contents will go as per your layout.